# Undestanding of Capacity Calculation Algorithm in HashMap

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, bitwise-operators

I am interested to know the working of capacity calculation algorithm in HashMap.

where if we Create the Object HashMap with some required capacity 20 , then the algorithm will always calculate the next highest capacity i.e (2^x >20)

The below is the jdk implementation .....

```
static final int tableSizeFor(int cap) {
    int n = cap - 1;
    n |= n >>> 1;
    n |= n >>> 2;
    n |= n >>> 4;
    n |= n >>> 8;
    n |= n >>> 16;
    return (n < 0) ? 1 : (n >= MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) ? MAXIMUM_CAPACITY : n + 1;
}
```

can someone explain me how the above algorithm works , what happens at each step .

I have understood that at each step they are dividing the number 2 and doing bitwise Or to older value.
and this they are doing because they have to allocate the next (2^x) value greater than n,

But can someone please help in explaining me in each step what happens with some numbers, i tried to debug but feeling complicated.

I have some implementation in mind like below..

```
private static int calculateCapacity(int cap){

    int max_capcity = 256;
    if(cap<16){
        return 16;
    }else if(cap <32){
        return 32;
    }else if(cap <64){
        return 64;
    }else if(cap < 128){
        return 128;
    }
    return max_capcity;
}
```

the above implementation can be used in stead of the complex bit wise and right shift one what is the significance of that.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this has changed in JDK 11 

`int n = -1 >>> Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(cap - 1)` 
Keeping the last line the same as in JDK 1.8. 
Which is easier to understand with less cluttering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This algorithm is a fast way to determine the smallest power of `2` which is larger than or equal to the given `cap`.

The way it works is it computes the number which has only one bit set, and this bit is at a position higher than all the other bits in your original number (or at the highest bit of the original number if it has only one bit set). To do so, it set all bits smaller than the leading bit to `1`, and then adds `1`.

Here is how it works for a positive number, written `001XXXXXXXXX` (the bits after the leading bit do not matter):

```
int n = cap - 1;    // will not change anything to the leading bit except
                    // if cap is already a power of 2. In that case,  
                    // we had cap = 001000000000 and now n = 000111111111 and
                    // the other lines won't change anything, we just have to
                    // do +1 in the end and we're done, n = cap;
                    // otherwise, let's assume that not every 'X' is a '0'

n |= n >>> 1;       // n >>> 1 = 0001XXXXXXX
                    // so    n = 0011XXXXXXX

n |= n >>> 2;       // n >>> 2 = 000011XXXXX
                    // so    n = 001111XXXXX

n |= n >>> 4;       //       n = 0011111111X

n |= n >>> 8;       //       n = 00111111111

n |= n >>> 16;      //       n = 00111111111

return n + 1;       //  result = 01000000000
```

For negative numbers, `n` is negative at every line because the sign bit is always `1`, so the result will be `1`.